# what is wrong with my unix scripts

Tags: bash, shell, unix

```
#!/bin/bash

while echo -n "Player's name?"
    read name
    [ $name != 'ZZZ' ]

do
searchresult=$(grep [$name] playername)
if [ $searchresult=0 ]

then

    echo -n "if See target (T/t) or team name (M/m)?"

    read team
    read target

    while [ [ $target!=T ] || [ $team!=M ] ]

        do

        echo "Please enter only T or M."
        done

        if $target=T
        then
            grep [ $name ] targetselected

        else

            grep [ $name ] teamselected

        fi

else

echo 'no such player'

fi

done
echo You are now exited search
```

## error msg - line 10: [: too many arguments, what is that mean?

Comment: you should put `read` inside the `while`, otherwise your `while` could never return false, since it does the same thing everytime?

Comment: it'd be helpful if you pointed out where line 10 is, coz line 10 in the above is a blank line.

Comment: thanks, line 10 is if [ $searchresult=0 ]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which line 10 in posted code you are pointing to but I found few issues with your posted code as

the line `while [ [ $target!=T ] || [ $team!=M ] ]` should be

```
while [ $target!="T" ] || [ $team!="M" ]
```

Also, `if $target=T` should accordingly be `if $target="T"`

Answer (score 0):

The two lines:

```
searchresult=$(grep [$name] playername)
if [ $searchresult=0 ]
```

are very wrong.  If you are trying to determine if the `grep` succeeds, it is best to do:

```
if grep -q "$name" playername; then ...
```

Putting grep in `$()` and assigning to searchresult has you comparing the output of `grep` rather than checking its exit status.  And the spaces that are missing around the `=` in the second line are very wrong.  Assuming `searchresult` is a string that contains no whitespace and only alphanumeric characters, the line `if [ $searchresult=0 ]` will always evaluate to true because the string "$searchresult=0" is always non-empty.  (If searchresult is the empty string then `$searchresult=0` is the string `=0` which is non-empty, so the test succeeds.)  It is highly unlikely that you intend to be testing whether or not that string is empty.  The exact error that you are seeing indicates that the `grep` is assigning a value to `searchresult` which contains whitespace.  In that case `[ $searchresult=0 ]` (without double quotes around `$searchresult`) is being parsed by `[` as multiple arguments (split on the whitespace in `$searchresult`), and the error is telling you that there are too many arguments.